# Do action only ONCE when NavigationDrawer is OPENING

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I've been looking a solution for this quite some time. So this is what I'm trying to achieve. I have a NavigationDrawer implemented with the following menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
        android:title="Dashboard" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_logbook"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logbook"
        android:title="Logbook" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_context"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_context"
        android:title="Context" />
 </group>
</menu>
```

When there's new context to be added, I want to show this to the user in the navigation drawer by adding the amount of new updates between brackets. Like this for example: `Context (2)` when there are two new updates.

I want to check this every time when the Drawer opens, but preferably only once, because there's a pretty heavy SQL query behind it. I know I can use the `onDrawerOpened()` and `onDrawerClosed()`, but I don't like this solution because of the fact the number will be updated suddenly only when the drawer is completely open. So it will stay one number, until it's completely open, by which it then will change. This just looks silly. So that's why I would want to change it once when the navigation drawer starts opening. I found no decent states to check this with the listener, since there is only `STATE_IDLE`, `STATE_DRAGGING` or `STATE_SETTLING` and nothing specifing for when it's opening and closing, just dragging and settling.

Additionally I also would like to keep the title of the fragment Context to stay "Context" and not also change to "Context (2)". Which happens in my current code:

```
mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            mDrawer,
            mToolbar,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close
){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            if (slideOffset != 0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onDrawerSlide() in update amount");
                int amount = db.getAmountNoContext();
                String sourcestring = "Context <b>(" + amount + ")</b>";
                mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setTitle(Html.fromHtml(sourcestring));
            }
        }
};
```

This is working for changing the menu title in the Navigation drawer, but it also gets called many times in a row, because the offset keeps changing. And this is because of the SQL query not ideal. I also tried to set it to a specific float value like `0.01`, but it's not getting triggered. Also I would like to remind that I would like to change the menu title back when the navigation drawer is closed, so the fragment title in the ActionBar just says "Context". I've done my research, but it seems like I just have a really specific problem? Maybe one of you guys have an idea. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" my problem for now by simply using a boolean to keep track if the SQL query is already exectued. If so the boolean is set to true and the condition will not be entered again until the drawer is completely closed by using the `onDrawerClosed()` function. I'll do it like this until maybe someone else comes up with a better solution. My solution looks now like this:

```
mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            mDrawer,
            mToolbar,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close
){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            if (slideOffset != 0 && !contextUpdated) {
                int amount = db.getAmountNoContext();
                String sourcestring = "Context (" + amount + ")";
                NavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setTitle(Html.fromHtml(sourcestring));
                contextUpdated = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            contextUpdated = false;
        }
};
```

For changing the title of the action bar back to the regular title without brackets. I just manually set the title in the `onCreateView()` of the fragment by doing this:

MainActivity:

```
public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

Fragment:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Context");
```